# How to express a complex object in a JSLint @param declaration

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have an object which is created on the fly (i.e. it is not a class), with the following structure:

```
    [
        {
            keys: [ 'a', 'b' ],
            info: [
                {
                    key: 'a',
                    data: [
                        {
                            position: 10.0,
                            value: 100.0
                        }   // repeated
                    ]
                }  // repeated
            ],
            sign: -1,
            atZero: true,
            virtual: false
        } // repeated
    ]
```

I have a function which processes such structures (that are all expected to have the same layout). I use WebStorm, which runs JSLint, and reports any parameter type errors by referring to the JSLint comments. I would like WebStorm to check the type of this parameter.

If I wish to tell JSLint that the parameter to, or return value from, a method is such a structure, how do I do so?

Comment: You shouldn't need to/can't. Can you give a more specific example of what you'd like to do? I think this sort of object sniffing will need to/should occur outside of a generic "code quality tool".

Comment: Have edited the question to try to make it clearer why I want to do this. I don't want any 'sniffing', I just want JSLint to verify (statically) that the actual parameter passed conforms to the expected layout.

Comment: Yep, out of luck unless you want to extend jslint.js yourself (but even then, I'm not sure how it can verify parameter types outside of running code, so perhaps I'm still missing something).  You might be interested in something like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) if you want to inject strongly typed conventions into your JavaScript code.

Comment: Odd, it seems able to check class, array and built in types OOK and I have seen example code which specifies the contents of "anonymous" types (but the syntax I saw doesn't work - e.g. "{ a:Number, b:string }").